# Aggregate data across dataframes based on string in first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering what the most economical way to aggregate information from several dataframes into one new one would be based on matching an ID.

Each df has a "participant_id" column and each row has a different participant ID. I want to end up with one df that has one participant_id column and a score from each of the other df's in the other columns.

So I must need a variable to hold the participant ID, loop through each row and lift the necessary columns. Then all of the respective scores need to be put on the appropriate row, associated with the correct participant ID.

I am not sure if this is the best way to approach the problem? At what point does matching the participant ID make sense? Early or late?

**Input data and expected outputs:**

```
### three datasets 

d1 = {'part_id': ['PartID_1234', 'PartID_5678'], 'col2': [1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'part_id': ['PartID_1234', 'PartID_5678'], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

d3 = {'part_id': ['PartID_5678', 'PartID_1234'], 'col2': [5, 6]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)


### aggregated dataset based on ID

import numpy as np

result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['PartID_1234', 1, 3, 6], ['PartID_5678', 2, 4, 5]]))
```

Comment: Please add some input data, code, and expected outputs.

Comment: Edited to include.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with `how='outer'` for the outer join effect you are expecting like:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='part_id', how='outer').merge(df3, on='part_id', how='outer')

    part_id     col2_x  col2_y  col2
0   PartID_1234   1        3    6
1   PartID_5678   2        4    5
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! However, I am losing about 15 rows of data on merge. What might this indicate and how could I resolve it?

I guess it may mean that a score is missing for one of the tests, so it removes the ID entirely. Could we instead just have it enter a "null" in that spot an keep the other scores for that ID?

Comment: Check the edit, you need outer join, merge does inner join by default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for each `DataFrame` for index by column `part_id` in list comprehension:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [x.set_index('part_id')['col2'] for x in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)

             0  1  2  3
0  PartID_1234  1  3  6
1  PartID_5678  2  4  5
```

If want first column in index:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [x.set_index('part_id')['col2'] for x in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)

             0  1  2
PartID_1234  1  3  6
PartID_5678  2  4  5
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there are different column names other than 'col2' and different numbers of columns to include per separate dataframe.

Comment: @SebSilas - Can you change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?